# Mobile app seamlessly open web browser with logged in user

Tags: android, ios, mobile, browser

I working on a mobile app that has some functionality that is not implemented natively but only on an external website. The user is logged in into the app, but when opening the external links (both in a webview and in the external browser) it has to log in again to access the functionality.

Is there any way to authenticate the user in the browser too without compromising security and/or user experience?
Any experience / best practice to share?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using something like a REST API to log in then it may be returning something like a session token in the response cookies so that subsequent requests to the API will know which user they refer to. For that case you would need to copy the API cookies into the URL request for the web view or into the web view's cookie store before making the request, as I recall.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm using a REST API to get authenticated from the app, and I get and access token to talk to the api. But if I want to open a webpage from the app (both webview or deeplinking in the browser) it feels a bit unsafe to share that access token. You meant that I should add that (or session token) into the URLRequest parameters?